# Can't connect to school servers using PC, but other devices work

Tags: ssh, putty, connection

I started to have this weird problem recently, and I cannot figure out why. The error I receive is "connection timed out".

- I cannot connect to the school servers (server01.xyz.edu -- for coding assignments) using my PC (PuTTY), whereas I can do it using my smartphone.
- This problem only occurs when I'm using WiFi. When connected to the school network via Ethernet, I can SSH to the servers without any problem.
- Again, this problem occurs only on my PC. I'm in the school's .11ac network.
- I can ping the servers, but I can't SSH or Telnet.

I use DHCP, so I don't believe it's related to IP configuration.

Do you have any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Are you using school-provided Wi-Fi? Do they provide more than one network? Have you contacted your school's network administrators yet?

Comment: Yes, it's the school's own WiFi network. There's only one network. I couldn't contact the IT department yet since it's the weekend. I have a project due by tomorrow and I have to spend most of the day outside the dorm, and so don't have the chance to use the Ethernet at all times. That's why I'm trying to figure out a solution now.

Comment: Try in elevated CMD the commands `netsh int ip reset` and `ipconfig /flushdns`, then reboot. (To address me an answer, please add in it the string `@harrymc`.)

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately the connection still times out.

Comment: What is your network adapter model and driver (check in Device Manager), to see if a later driver exists.

Comment: @harrymc It's Killer 1525, and I've made sure that all the network drivers are up-to-date.

Comment: You analysis is flawed that your MAC is not blocked since it's working for Ethernet, as the WiFi adapter will most likely have a different MAC. Try to borrow a portable WiFi adapter to see if it works for you.

Comment: @harrymc That's right -- I'm not sure why I completely skipped that. Will try to find one and see if it'll do the trick. And seems like I'll have to pay a visit to the IT.

Comment: @harrymc I couldn't find a portable adapter, but instead connected the Ethernet port in my dorm to a wireless router, then connected to the router via WiFi. I can connect to the servers currently with no issues. Is it safe to say now that the problem is not related to my MAC address or WiFi adapter & driver?

Comment: Yes, as safe as anything else. It might only have needed a reboot, or getting a different IP address by DHCP. Whatever it was, if it happens again consult the IT people.